# improving a question: "It does not meet our quality standards." error

Tags: support

I'm getting the following error message when I try to post a question:

"It does not meet our quality standards."

This is the text of the question I'm trying to ask:

"is there a way to configure a specific locale for just one app (ignoring the default)?

Thanks"

This is the title: "set locale for a single app in linux"

And the tags: "linux" and "locale"

Could someone tell me how to improve it?

Comment: I don't know if these things are relevant to the error message you received or not but two things stand out to me. Lack of proper capitalization and the unnecessary and undesirable "Thanks".

Answer (score 5):

Chances are this is happening because what you're asking is too short. It's a simple question, yes, but could be expanded with what you've tried already (if anything). Including the app in question would be a good idea in general.

secondly, as-written, that question would likely earn 'off topic' close votes. We do a lot of linux stuff here, but there is [a StackExchange site with generic Linux/Unix stuff as their topic.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) Because of that, we need some hint that what you're working on is topical to *this* site, and covers system administration in some way.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about the linux site, I will ask there then. I can add more text, but I really think that the question is just valid as it is. For example, the app, in this case, is irrelevant.

Answer (score -5):

I happens to me a few minutes ago. The question was a very short one.
I had to add hello and thank you.

Comment: errrr, we don't necessarily like greetings and such in questions. We usually go out of our way to delete them, in fact. The greetings and thanks, not the whole question.

Comment: What Holocryptic said -- There is always something more useful you can add than "Thanks" or "Hello" - see what @sysadmin1138 mentioned above.

Comment: Holocrypt and voretaq7 Perfectly understood.